# Conflict jquery UI tabs and Bootstrap 3 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, conflict

Conflict occurs when building jQuery tabs

If do so, it does not work dropdown menu (bootstrap)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
       });
</script>
```

If do so, it does not work tabs (jquery UI)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $.noConflict();
       $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
       });
    </script>
```

What to do to work and jquery tabs and dropdown bootstrap ?

Comment: Include a customized bootstrap js excluding the tabs from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#javascript-components)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery.noConflict();
       jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
       });
    </script>
```